# Force linux to use php as php55

Tags: php, linux, fedora

Helllo,
I have a little problem here.

I have PHP 5.3 installed and it's accessible via `php` command, I also have php 5.5 accessible as `php55` command.

Now I need to force linux to use `php55` when I write `php` command.

Simple way: How I switch the versions of php?

I am using Fedora 21 OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an alias:

```
alias php="php55"
```

Now if you type `php` it uses `php55`

Comment: thanks I will try, is there a way to revert the change? Like to get what is the current settings of "php" alias (and create backup)?

Comment: Yes you can use `unalias php` to unset the alias

Answer (score 1):

PHP typically installs its binary at `/usr/bin/php` (not all installs might do that tho, so YMMV). So what you could do is symlink the PHP binary to your `php55` command like this (assumes the paths are correct)

```
ln -s /path/to/php55 /usr/bin/php
```